# Персистентные очереди - это одно и тоже, что и устойчивые очереди?

Tags: терминология, очередь, rabbitmq

Персистентные очереди - это одно и тоже, что и устойчивые очереди?
Правильно ли понимаю, что это просто способность очереди сохранять сообщения при аварийном завершении или перезагрузке сервера?